# Showing only selected features from attribute table on layer using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes, qgis-2

One of the layers has around 5000 attribute entries, based on a CSV file of species records. All the features are of course shown on the map layer. How can I select a specific class of features so that only they appear on a map, so that for example a distribution map for a species can be generated. I have tried "Advanced Filter (Expression)" so that the Attribute Table shows only the required species, but it still shows all the attributes on the map layer.

I am using QGIS 2.10.1.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/111784/how-to-display-only-selected-features-on-map. The answer from Vesanto is rather cool, but requires a plugin.

Answer (score 8):

1. Double click on your layer in the table of contents to go to Layer Properties.
2. Go to the general tab (hammer and screwdriver icon).
3. Look for "Feature subset" and enter an expression (perhaps using the Query Builder button). For example: `"species" = 'homo sapiens'`. This would restrict the features to only those records meeting this criteria.

Example:[image]

Answer (score 7):

The previous answer is not valid anymore for QGIS 3.4:

1. Double click on your layer in the table of contents to go to Layer Properties. (like
   in QGIS 2)
2. Go to Source Tab
3. Click on Query Builder below the "provide feature filter" section

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('layername')[0]
layer.setSubsetString("'10'" + ' LIKE "fieldcolumn"')
```

Comment: You're using typographical (curly) quotes rather than straight ASCII quotes. I don't know of any programming language where that works.

Comment: I have updated my answer. My fault. Thanks for your tips.