# QGIS Control layer under the group layer display shortcut keys

Tags: qgis, layers, shortcuts

In the ArcMap, you can hold down the Alt key and select the layer to show only the selected layer, and hold down the Ctrl key to select the layer that can be displayed at all levels on the same level.

If you select the layer under the group layer, The above operation will only function in the layer under the group layer.

Does QGIS have a similar shortcut?

Answer (score 1):

No.

Although I do not understand what you mean with:

> ... can be displayed at all levels on the same level.

There is a way to show only the selected features. See my answer in: [Displaying only selected features on map in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/111784/displaying-only-selected-features-on-map-in-qgis)