# Where is Query Builder in QGIS 3.0?

Tags: qgis, query, qgis-3, user-interface

How to find the Query Builder in the freshly released QGIS version 3.0?

<sub>In previous versions (2.x), it could be found as mentioned in [Displaying only selected features on map in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/111784/displaying-only-selected-features-on-map-in-qgis/111933#111933)</sub>

Answer (score 10):

In QGIS3, the query builder button is located in the `Layer Properties` dialog, then in the `Source` tab, and finally in the bottom right corner of `Provider feature filter`.

[image: Query building in QGIS 3.0]

Answer (score 2):

As shown in the below picture, you find the Query Builder by opening the Layer Properties and going to 'Source' menu. Under Feature Filter, click on the [Query Builder] button to open the Query Builder.

[image]