# Features color based on layer's color in QGIS

Tags: qgis, symbology, overlapping-features, rule-based

Is there a way to synchronize the selection color with a layer's color in QGIS?. 
Following this post [https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/111784/displaying-only-selected-features-on-map-in-qgis#*=*](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/111784/displaying-only-selected-features-on-map-in-qgis#_=_)  I am able to change the order and apparently color of selected features with a based-rule symbology, however the selection color does not take rule based color only width and line type.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can change the color of selected features in two places:

1. In the QGIS Options dialogue (Settings menu > Options...):

   [image]
2. In the Project Properties dialogue (Project menu > Propeties):

   [image]

The selection color you set in one of those dialogues will **override** any color you set in the Layer Styling panel.

As she_weeds commented, you can choose a partially-transparent selection color. That way you'll be able to partially see the color set in the layer styling panel. This setting will affect all the layers in your project, so don't choose a fully-transparent selection color.

Comment: In fact using this dialogue box you can set the selection colour to transparent and therefore let the expression-based colour show through - but I'd strongly recommend against making your selections totally invisible, OP, as it affects all your layers!